# Removing illegal characters with Automator

Tags: linux, macos, mac, bash, automator

I've been trying to write a Mac Automator service to remove illegal characters from filenames.
I have it working, but the solution is a little inelegant and I was wondering if anyone would have a better solution.

I'm running the following Bash script which has the selected file passed to it as an argument.

```
for f in "$@"
do

cd $(dirname "$f")
mv "${f##*/}" $(echo "${f##*/}" | sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g')

done
```

It does this

```
cd /Desktop/test/
mv some file %^& test.txt some_file_____test.txt
```

`cd`'ing into the directory was the only way I could get the `mv` to work. It would either not be able to find the file, or it rename the entire filepath, i.e.

```
/Desktop/test/some file %^& test.txt to _Desktop_test_some_file_____test.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the dirname/basename to split up your variable $f into $fdir and $fbase, and only edit $fbase, and stay out of the dir, but it really doesn't look a whole lot better than your `cd` solution... (don't think it needs the parameter expansion to remove the slash part in $fbase, so gets slightly smaller. Might even be able to use pattern substitution instead of `sed`, but `sed` already works so good enough)

```
for f in "$@"
do
  fbase=$(basename "$f")
  fdir=$(dirname "$f")
  mv "${fdir}${fbase}" "${fdir}$(echo "${fbase}" | sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g')"
done
```

---

But I'm also wondering if your `for f in "$@"` might be getting caught up with illegal filenames too, not separating out the $f's properly without some IFS-fiddling, but I'm betting that Automator takes care of those.

Another option might be to run `find` and then use it's `-exec` or `-execdir` or even `xargs` to find & rename files, and there is a `rename` program that can do things like "translate uppercase names to lower, you'd use" `rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *` but those might not work well with Automator.

Actually, I'll try a quick test to see what `rename` alone does with a filename with full paths... an unexpected "no such file" while echoing the correct full path:

```
$ rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' "/home/me/Downloads/NEWFILE-Z1.txt" 
Can't rename /home/me/Downloads/NEWFILE-Z1.txt /home/me/downloads/newfile-z1.txt: No such file or directory
```

Doesn't look like a big improvement over `mv, but`rename` could cut down on the subshells & pipes & echos...

```
$ rename -v 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g' New\ space\ file.txt 
New space file.txt renamed as New_space_file.txt
```

I'll put it in the script, smaller but it's back to `cd`, and the `"` quoting works "around" the subshell call too:

```
for f in "$@"
do
  cd $(dirname "$f")
  rename 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g' "$(basename "$f")"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that seems to confuse the path and the filename though, it looks for /Desktop/testsome file %^& test.txt. missing the last / in the dirname. I'm not really aware of IFS, I'm quite new to this, sort of learning on the fly. I like your solution though, if it could work.

Comment: Actually putting a / between ${fdir}${fbase##*/} like so ${fdir}/${fbase##*/} seems to do the job.

Comment: I think the base/dir parts are ok, but nothing beats some good `echo` testing. basename and dirname do cut off the connecting `/`... I also saw a possible problem with quoting too, there were already double-quotes in the `echo` and single quotes in the `sed`, so getting them all "wrapped" with quotes for move looked troublesome. I'll double-quote the second `${fdir}` alone

Comment: Thanks, it's working as follows, mv "${fdir}/${fbase##*/}" "${fdir}"/$(echo "${fbase##*/}" | sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g')

Comment: The IFS stuff can be quite confusing, it's mentioned in my `man bash` (search for IFS). Decides where one "name" ends and another begins, often confused by newlines (which could be in a naughty filename). Automator probably figures that part out, so it may not be a concern here, but it comes up in bash sometimes. I'll edit in another idea too.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the simpler I can keep the better, this seems to be a great solution for me.

Comment: No problem. Changed a few details, using dirname & basename shouldn't need the parameter expansion/editing with `${##:}`, and the subshell works "around" or takes precedence over the quoting. `man bash` has pages and pages of info, but I wouldn't tackle it without searching for exactly what you want (or being trapped in a room with nothing else to do ;)